# How to Store or Structure Configuration Data into MySQL - Php, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a project in which I would like to store data which has nothing to do with application business logic (nor have anything to do with table relationships such as: 1 to many, many to many, 1 to 1 and so on) but instead it is more of an Application settings.

Things like:

```
Color of the Text,
Email addresses,
Logo,
Some title text,
few checkboxes, 
few radio buttons.
```

I want to allow admin to change this settings. But, I am not sure how to dump all this information inside mysql without creating several tables. I think this is a normal thing required in most of the applications.

What is the best approach to save such settings? MySQL is what I think. But feel free to enlighten me with better method.

Comment: Store it as [JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) maybe?

Comment: May be following "options" table of wordpress database will give you a clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one table,from the the application settings examples you gave , Fields called"Property", "Value"  and "Unit"

For example 
Property : Color
Value: #FFFFF
Unit: hex

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

By reading your question, I guess you are supposed to develop portal application, where all features and GUI settings are stored in DB (database could be anyone MySQL/MS-SQL/Oracle). In this case, admin get the right to tweak values and GUI and features get enabled or disabled.

As for as suggestion is concern, you are on right track! DB operations are same as in other applications.